# How to customize width of multiple fillCol?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm looking for a way to customize the width of `fillCol` in the UI. I would like to set the width of Sidebar1 to 20%, Main to 60%, and Sidebar2 to 20%. I tried to use `%` CSS units, but it didn't work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fillPage(
   
    fillRow(
            tags$b("Header"), 
            height = "5vh"),
    fillRow(
        fillCol(tags$b("Sidebar1"), width = "10%"),
        fillCol(tags$b("Main"), width = "80%"),
        fillCol(tags$b("Sidebar2"), width = "10%"),
           
            height = "90vh"),
    fillRow(
        tags$b("Footer"), 
        height = "5vh"))
    

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Right now, it seems they are spread across equally.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `flex=c(1,3,1)` to get 20%, 60% and 20% display as shown below.

```
ui <- fillPage(
  
  fillRow(
    tags$b("Header"), height = "5vh"),
  fillRow(flex = c(1,3,1),
    plotOutput("plotLeft",  height = "50%"),
    plotOutput("plotMiddle", height = "50%"),
    plotOutput("plotRight",  height = "50%") , height = "90vh"
    ),
  fillRow(
    tags$b("Footer"), 
    height = "5vh"))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plotLeft <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
  output$plotMiddle <- renderPlot(plot(pressure))
  output$plotRight <- renderPlot(plot(AirPassengers))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]